# What should I say "Had Happened" Or "happened"?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, past-vs-past-perfect

Due to some reason I could not completed my task yesterday. Is it correct to say Today that?

I really don't Know what had happened to me. I could not complete my task yesterday.

or only simple past tense will do

I really don't know what happened to me yesterday. I could not complete my task.

Comment: I could not *complete* my task--modal auxiliaries (*can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*) take infinitive complements. I see nothing to suggest a past perfect would be called for here--there's no reference to a past time *after* you were unable to complete your task.

Comment: I believe that the intent is to communicate that at some time the person wasn't able to complete a task and didn't know what had happened (at an earlier time) to cause it.

Comment: Have you disappeared?

Answer (score 3):

We normally use a Perfect tense when we want to:

1. Talk about how a verb before a time of focus on affected that time
2. Talk about a verb beginning before the time of focus which continued until or through the time of focus

The first one can include a "life experience" such as:

> When I first went to China I had never met a Chinese person before.

Also, it can be about an earlier change in the situation affecting the time  of focus:

> When I got home, I noticed that someone had cooked a chocolate cake.

Verbs continuing to the time of focus have an "up to now" (Present Perfect) or "up to that time" (Past Perfect) feeling:

> He was drunk because he'd had too much to drink.

(Of course, we may also use the Continuous Aspect, as in "he'd been drinking", but I'm just clarifying use of Perfect tenses for this answer.)

In your example, most native speakers would usually say the second (using Past Simple).  Part of the reason is that many native speakers don't use Perfect tenses properly these days.  (Not a good reason, but it's true.)  Also, many of us would probably think of the situation in a series, like X happened and then I couldn't complete my task.  We're thinking about the time of the first verb, then we're thinking about the time of the second verb.  Compare to this:

> I don't know why, but I lost my car keys yesterday.  I couldn't drive home.

You could also say:

> I couldn't drive home, because I'd lost my car keys.

But in the first case we're thinking *sequentially* -- one thing happened after another.

Returning to your examples:

> I really don't know what had happened to me. I could not complete my task yesterday.

This is okay, but only if in the first sentence we're thinking about the time when I couldn't complete my task -- that time was being affected by *something* happening to me.

> I really don't know what happened to me yesterday. I could not complete my task.

This is the most natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect tenses have a sense of "completed" or "this is not something we have to worry about anymore."

> I really don't Know what had happened to me. I could not complete my task yesterday.

The thing that "had happened" you are considering/implying/expecting that it won't happen again, because it was unexpected, rare, or you have made sure it won't happen again (or you want to make a superior believe this).

> I really don't know what happened to me yesterday. I could not complete my task.

The thing that "happened" could happen again, or it's something that occasionally happens to everyone.